# Kubernetes pod spec requires imagePullSecrets that does NOT match referenced secret?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-secrets

Trying to following the use-case examples given in the official Kubernetes documentation for using secrets as environment variables (referenced [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-as-container-environment-variables) ), I made both my secret and my deployment yaml (which includes a pod spec) as follows:

Secret yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  LOCAL_UID: dsdgvreRBRBBsdd=
  LOCAL_PWD: MmSDkfKDODbOU4NCg==
```

which is written to the namespace by doing:
`kubectl apply -f my-secret.yaml`

Likewise, here is the deployment Yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          env:
            - name: REPO_APP_URL
              value: https://repo.myco.com/project.tar.gz
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: my-secret
          image: repo.myco.com/images/node-alpine:0.1.6
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 15
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcredepg
```

- note shown above (but is in the deployment yaml) are the Service and Ingress specs.

This is run by doing the following

`kubectl apply -f my-app.yaml`

This actually works great given:

1. the `imagePullSecrets` directive is included in the deployment YAML.
2. that the `name` value given in the `imagePullSecrets` section is **not** the actual secret used in the  `envFrom: - secretRef:` section.

If I try to set the name of the `imagePullSecrets` name field to `my-secret`, the pod fails to load (saying `Error from server (BadRequest): container "my-app" in pod "my-app-597bb6c9b4-lh8rg" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled`).

Also, it won't allow me to simply remove the `imagePullSecrets` section of the YAML in the pod spec, even though the documentation claims it its optional.

So, the only way this will work is if I include the `imagePullSecrets` reference to a valid secrets that I am **not** using in my `envFrom: - secretRef:` section. I am sure I am missing some logical obvious issue here. Can anyone shed light on this??

Comment: @MikolajS. apparently, yes he brought up the correct issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagePullSecrets` has a different format than just the ID and password. You need to specify the registry FQDN and the username and password. You can find more information in [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Comment: Unfortunately, you are answering a question I did not ask.   Look at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-as-container-environment-variables  this is the use case I am working on. It is documented in k8s docs, but the details of my issue is detailed in my post above, which is not related to the answer you gave.

Comment: the problem you are having is that kubelet can not pull the image from your private container registry and it is because your registry requires authentication and the secret you provided as imagePullSecrets does not have proper type and format. it has nothing to do with it being used in envFrom

Comment: by  private container registry do you mean the fact `image: repo.myco.com/images/node-alpine:0.1.6` requires something in a dockerconfigjson format or such?